# Laravel and AngularJs - Simple route doesn't call controller

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I have a laravel application and I want to use AngularJs in a blade partial.
I've included all files I need, added the ng-app and get no JavaScript errors. 
The problem is that the route doesn't call the controller for some reason.

App:

```
var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies']);
```

Route:

```
// ROUTES
weatherApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {    
    $routeProvider    
      .when('/weather', {
        templateUrl: '/weather',
        controller: 'coordinatesController'
      })    
});
```

Controller:

```
// CONTROLLERS
weatherApp.controller('coordinatesController', function() {    
    alert('hello');    
});
```

Blade Template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    {{ HTML::style('css/public.css'); }}

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    {{ HTML::script('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-resource.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-cookies.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/ngAutocomplete.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/geolocation.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/weather/weatherApp.js') }}

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    @if (Session::has('message'))
        <div class="flash alert">
            <p>{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    @yield('main')
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Blade Section:

```
@extends('layouts.public')

@section('main')
    {{ HTML::script('js/weather/weatherApp.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/weather/routes.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/weather/services.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/weather/controllers.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/weather/directives.js') }}
    <div ng-app="weatherApp">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-right">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="btn btn-default">{{ HTML::linkRoute('home', 'Dashboard') }}</li>
                        <li class="btn btn-default">{{ HTML::linkRoute('backbone.login', 'Backbone') }}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Weather Forecast</h3>
            <form ng-submit="submit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="city" ng-autocomplete select-input-value />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Get Forecast" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody class="table-striped table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Latitude</th>
                        <th>Longitude</th>
                        <th>Temperature</th>
                        <th>Weather</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
            <hr>

            <footer class="text-center">
                <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Comment: what error do you get on your console?

Comment: show us your blade file

Comment: I've edited the post and added the blade files

Comment: so, where's ``ng-controller``?

Comment: @KiwiJuicer I've added the answer, you can accept it for further readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the [ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) directive.

To make you controller working you need to wrap related markup to something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="coordinatesController">
  …
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo , in your routing you are looking for `coordinatesControllers` and controller declaration does not have an `s` at the end.

I assume this is the issue, your use of the word `controller` doesn't specify backend or client side controllers

Comment: I changed that, there is still no difference

Comment: Not clear what issue is then, inspect the ajax request for template in network tab of dev tools and make sure it is succeeeding

Comment: They are all successful with 200 or 304

Comment: so you are saying the alert never fires? WHat does happen, particularly in url? Any errors thrown also?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, maybe try moving your `ng-app` directive out of your blade view into the blade template. I once had a similar issue with the `ng-controller` directive.

```
<body>

<div class="container" data-ng-app="weatherApp">
    @if (Session::has('message'))
        <div class="flash alert">
            <p>{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    @yield('main')
</div>

</body>
```

Also make sure you specify `.otherwise` in your routes.

```
weatherApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {    
    $routeProvider    
      .when('/weather', {
        templateUrl: '/weather',
        controller: 'coordinatesController'
      })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
    });
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07